# Implementing vfork() in xv6

Tags: system-calls, xv6

If I want to add my system call vfork(copy on write) what exactly need to be edited in syscall.c? Where would I add my fragment of vfork's code. In short, how would I implement vfork in xv6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i add a system call / utility in xv6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6)

Answer (score 1):

For adding the system call in xv6's shell; amend the following files:

- **sysproc.c** add the real implementation of your method here
- **syscall.h** define the position of the system call vector that connect
  to your implementation
- **user.h** define the function that can be called through the shell
- **syscall.c** external define the function that connect the shell and the
  kernel, use the position defined in **syscall.h** to add the function to the system call vector
- **usys.S** use the macro to define connect the call of user to the system
  call function

Also you can check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6).