# How to pass a value into a system call function in XV6?

Tags: c, function, system, call, xv6

I am attempting to create a simple priority based scheduler in XV6.  To do this, I also have to create a system call that will allow a process to set its priority.  I have done everything required to create the system call as discussed here and elsewhere:

[how do i add a system call / utility in xv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6)

The problem is, I cannot pass any variables when I call the function, or rather, it runs like nothing is wrong but the correct values do not show up inside the function.

Extern declaration (syscall.c):

```
...
extern int sys_setpty(void);

static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
...
[SYS_setpty]  sys_setpty,
};
```

Sys-call Vector (syscall.h):

```
#define SYS_setpty 22
```

Implementation (sysproc.c):

```
void
sys_setpty(int pid, int pty)
{
  cprintf("function pid: %d \n", pid);
  cprintf("function pty: %d \n", pty);
}
```

(defs.h & user.h):

```
void setpty(int, int);
```

Macro (usys.S):

```
SYSCALL(setpty)
```

Function call:

```
setpty(3, 50);
```

Output:

```
function pid: 16843009
function pty: 16843009
```

The values are always the same exact number: 16843009.  I have checked to see if the cprintf is working correctly by assigning values to pid and pty.  I have spent about 6 hours trying every possible combination of everything I can think of and I'm starting to think that there is no built in mechanism for passing values via a system call in XV6.  Am I missing something?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Passing arguments from user-level functions to kernel-level functions cannot be done in XV6.  XV6 has its own built-in functions for passing arguments into a kernel function.  For instance, to pass in an integer, the argint() function is called.  In the implementation that I used for the set-priority function, that would look something like:

```
argint(0, &pid);
```

... to get the first argument which is the Process ID, and:

```
argint(1, &pty);
```

... to get the second argument which is the desired priority. The function call from the user process looks like this:

```
setpty(getpid(), priority);
```

Comment: Thanks to your own answer +1 , I got how to pass parameters from user space to kernel space.  However I could not do priority based scheduling. :(