# In xv6, how can i make child process run first after fork()?

Tags: fork, xv6

I've seen plenty of related questions and replys, however, no one can provide a good solution, could you help me?

Add: we may need to add a system call to determine whether to use this order or not.

Answer (score 3):

Self ask, self answer, how **funny**!

- First, add a system call `int fork_winner(int winner)` which needs an integer argument. If `winner == 1`, child process runs first. If `winner == 0`, parent runs first as usual. To achieve this, you may need help from:

1. [how do i add a system call / utility in xv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6)

2. [how to pass a value into a system call function in xv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068394/how-to-pass-a-value-into-a-system-call-function-in-xv6)

The definition of `int sys_fork_winner(void)` is as follow which is in `sysproc.c`:

```
int 
sys_fork_winner(void)
{
  if(argint(0, &child_first) < 0) // fetch parameter
    return -1;  
  return 0;
}
```

- Second, set a global variable, for example, `child_first`, to save `winner`'s value.
- Third, modify `fork()` in `proc.c`. if `winner == 1`, call `yield()` after child process being created. Otherwise, do nothing.
- Finally, you may need a user program to test whether it works. The core code is follow:

```c
void test(){
    int i = 0;   
    int ret = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_TEST_TRIALS; i++)
    {
        printf(1, "\nTrial %d: ", i);
        ret = fork();
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf(1, "fork() failed (%d)\n", ret);
            exit();
        }
        else if (ret == 0) // child
        {
            printf(1, " child! ");
            exit();
        }

        // parent
        printf(1, " parent! ");
        if (ret != wait())
        {
            printf(1, "wait() failed!\n");
        }
    }

    printf(1, "\n");
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    printf(1,"Fork test\nSet child as winner");

    fork_winner(1);  
    test();

    printf(1,"\nSet parent as winner");
    fork_winner(0);//the default
    test();


    exit();
}
```

This [article](https://ampleux.wordpress.com/2018/02/22/how-to-add-a-user-program-to-xv6/) can help you add a user program to xv6.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you post your new system call. Moreover, I don't think you need to use a global variable, you could choose to call `yield()` in `fork_winner`.

Comment: In my case, system call is used to pass parameter which is needed by function `fork_winner()` in test program. The `fork_winner()`'s code has been put in which `child_first` is the global variable.

Comment: Can you please explain your second and third points? I have made changes in sysproc.c but after that, I am unsure how to access the child_first variable in the fork function. I tried using extern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code, one way is to use wait sys call right after fork(); this will make the parent process wait till child process completes

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "user/user.h"

int main(void) {
  
    int status;
    int pid = fork();
    wait(&status);
    
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Fork failed\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
            int pid = getpid();
            printf("child PID: %d \n", pid);

        exit(0);
    } else {
            int cid = getpid();
            printf("Parent ID : %d\n", cid);
        
    }

    
    exit(0);
```

}