# How do I add "top" system command to xv6?

Tags: linux, terminal, operating-system, system-calls, xv6

I am a beginner and don't know anything about writing system commands on my own.This is my class assignment. Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first to read the [xv6 book](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/xv6/book-rev8.pdf) along with the [xv6 printout](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/xv6/xv6-rev8.pdf) and with the actual [source code](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) in your favorite IDE. Take your time and actually read the book, it is easy to read and you'll see it will make a difference.

After you finish, go and read chapter 3 again and then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021774/how-do-i-add-a-system-call-utility-in-xv6) thread.